# Portable ISO image mounter for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, iso-image

What do you use as a portable ISO image mounter on Windows 7 (x86/x64)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) has a portable edition.  It requires Administrator access because it will need to install a kernel driver to handle mounting into the system's object namespace, but so will any other program that does the same thing.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this out!

Answer (score 2):

Since I rarely need to mount an ISO, but extract .zip archives more regularly, my preference is to use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the contents of an ISO to a folder.  This saves me from having to install a stand-alone utility to handle ISO files.

Answer (score 1):

From MakeUseOf (literally), 
[Mount CD or DVD Image Files Virtually Using A Portable App](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mount-cd-dvd-disk-images-using-a-portable-app/):

> Download the [**Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel v2.0.1.1**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe)

<sup>That reference comes from [Microsoft KB916902](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916902).</sup>

Comment: Thanks nik, but that's the tool of the devil :)

Comment: Will that even work in Windows 7 x86?  It's *definitely* not going to work on x64 since the driver is x86 only.  @FLX: You're already using their OS, so what's the difference?  ;-)

Comment: I've run this in 7 x64 and it worked without issue. I usually used Daemon Tools though. This was just for testing.

Comment: @music2myear: Really?  It worked?  Interesting.

Comment: @afrazier compatibility mode? program files(x86) folder? what are those for?